# STL Priority Queue: When/How Does Resorting Occur?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

If I have a STL priority_queue of structs, where priority is based on some attribute of the struct, and I change the attribute of one of the structs, such that the new order would be different, would the priority queue know to resort itself? Or would I have to remove it from the queue and push it in again? I read somewhere that the sorting is done when push() and pop() are called, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: No!  You should _never_ modify the "priority" of a value in a `priority_queue` (or the key of a `map` or `set`).  It will not resort itself.  Pop->Edit->Push.

Comment: How do you modify the struct? The queue will make a copy when you push it in, and after that there shouldn't really be a way to get a reference to the item in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you describe.

There are three methods for *pushing* items onto the priority-queue:

1. `push()` (which implies moving or copying the item in, rather than taking a reference)
2. Passing another container or an iterator range when the queue is constructed (this also involves making copies or moves, and then forming a heap on the copies; no references to the originals are retained)
3. `emplace()` (which implies creating a new item inside the queue, without being able to get a reference to it)

The only way to *access* elements is through the `top()` function, which returns a const-reference.

So there is no way to retain a reference to an item when pushing it, or to obtain a non-const-reference to an item already in the queue. Hence, there is no way to modify queue items directly.

The only way, in theory, to make a modification that would impact the sorting order is if the items on the queue contained pointers to external objects, and if the sorting order depended on the contents of those external objects. In this case, you could obviously modify those external objects while queue items still point to them. The sorting order would then become invalid – the priority queue would not update it since it wouldn't even know about the modification.

Answer (score 1):

The `priority_queue` `push()` and `pop()` member functions are defined in terms of the behavior of the `push_heap()` and `pop_heap()` library functions with the full contents of the underlying container passed in as the range.

Those function require that the range (except for the last item in the container on a `push_heap()`, since that's the item that is being added) "shall be a valid heap".  If you modify the contained elements such that the container is no longer a valid heap, then you'll get undefined behavior.

So if you need to modify an element in that manner, you'll need to do it by removing it, modifying it, then adding it back.  Alternatively, you could, mess with the contents then call `make_heap()` to rebuild the heap.

See C++11 23.6.4.3 "priority_queue members", 25.4.6.1 "push_heap", and 25.4.6.2 "pop_heap".

Answer (score 0):

It is most certainly not reordered the right way, at least this is not guaranteed. push() and pop() of the priority_queue just call std::push_heap() and std::pop_heap() of the underlying heap structure.

The effect of

```
push(const value_type& x)
```

is

```
c.push_back(x);
push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
```

according to the C++03 standard (23.2.3.2.2), where **c** is the underlying container of the queue and **comp** the ordering function.

One requirement of **push_heap** is that

> The range [first, last - 1] shall be a valid heap.

according to 25.3.6.1 of the C++03 standard.

If you modify the existing structure of the priority_queue this breaks the heap structure and it has to be remade using make_heap to be a valid heap structure again.

The priority_queue also has no way of knowing that you modified an element using an external reference/pointer since it is not notified by a call to one of its methods.

You should remove the element and add it again to achieve what you want. You could also use a completely different container where you have more flexibility about which element you want to remove and add again, like an std::map.